# How to read an Objective-C array in Swift? It's always returning nil

Tags: swift, objective-c, nsarray

I have a NSArray declared in .h file as

```
@interface ClassName : NSObject
{
NSArray *myArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myArray;
@end
```

In the .m file here is how I have it.

```
@implementation ClassName
NSArray* myArray;
```

I am trying to access this in Swift as given below.

```
var x = ClassName().myArray
```

`x` is always `nil`.

Comment: And what's the init of `ClassName`? Does it initialize the `myArray`

Comment: @Larme, no I haven't initialized it.

Comment: Well, there’s your problem :) your Objective C class needs an `–init` method to initialize its objects with a new array instance set

Comment: In Objective-C, `myArray` is currently just declared. But nowhere we see a `myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];` (and I would have expected a `NSMutableArray` if you want to add values to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your Objective-C class. You've declared the `myArray` property (which is fine), but you've also added a public instance variable of the same name in the header file and you created a global variable (not instance variable) of the same name in the .m file. The following is what you should have:

In the .h file:

```
@interface ClassName : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myArray;
@end
```

In the .m file:

```
@implementation ClassName

@end
```

That's it.

The next big issue is that you are accessing the `myArray` property but you never give it a value. This is why you always get `nil`.

This is no different than if you had a Swift class with an optional property that you never gave a value to.

Let's say you have the following Swift class:

```
class ClassName {
    var myArray: [Any]?
}
```

If you then did:

```
var x = ClassName().myArray
```

you would get `nil` just as you did using the Objective-C class. In both cases you need to create an instance of the class and assign an initial value to `myArray`.

```
var c = ClassName()
c.myArray = [ "Hi", "There" ]
```

Now you can access the array:

```
var x = c.myArray
```

---

BTW - assuming you want the array to hold specific types of values, you should update the property declaration in your Objective-C class.

For example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<NSString *> *myArray;
```

if you wanted an array of `NSString`.